# React component's state not updating in Jest unit test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a simple form as a React component. Upon clicking a button, handleSubmit() is called which makes a callout and clears the form if the callout is successful. I tried making a Jest unit test that tests if the form is cleared upon submission.

```
it('handles form submission', () => {
    Amplify.API.post = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve());
    EventEmitter.emit = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve());

    wrapper.setState({
        diocese: {
            name: 'My New Diocese',
            id: '123',
            generalCollectionOnly: false,
            aggregatePayments: false,
            aggregatePledges: false,
        },
    });

    footer.children().find(Button).at(1).simulate('click');
    expect(wrapper.state().diocese.name).toEqual('');
});
```

After debugging this, I can see that the form is submitted successfully and calls this.setState():

```
this.setState(() => ({
    diocese: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        generalCollectionOnly: false,
        aggregatePledges: false,
        aggregatePayments: false,
    },
    isLoading: false,
}));
```

However, the expect statement fails because the name still shows 'My New Diocese' even though it should be cleared. After doing some research, I thought that updating the wrapper would help:

```
wrapper.update();
```

However, it still shows that the component's state has not been cleared. Why is the state not updating in the test?

Comment: Can you share the code for the click handler?  (My guess is that it is doing some asynchronous work)

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors You are right. The handler was doing some asynchronous work and adding an await fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for the feedback. The problem was caused by the `handleSubmit()` doing asynchronous work. Adding an `await` in the Jest unit test fixed the issue. This is how the test looks:

```
it('handles form submission', async () => {
    Amplify.API.post = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve());
    EventEmitter.emit = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve());
    wrapper.setState({
        diocese: {
            name: 'My New Diocese',
            id: '123',
            generalCollectionOnly: false,
            aggregatePayments: false,
            aggregatePledges: false,
        },
    });
    await footer.children().find(Button).at(1).simulate('click');
    expect(wrapper.state().diocese.name).toEqual('');
});
```

The test passes now.

Comment: whoo saved one day of mine

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of test which I was writing with Jest and Enzyme: 
You don't need to setState, just pass to the wrapper of component an mocked object like this "**values**" in my example. Then you should know how and what component will render based on properties and values in object "**values**" which you pass.

```
it('Get Awerage Daily Wage label - Calculated', () => {
    const values = {
      wageEntryMethod: 'Calculated',
      grossWages: 45000,
      totalCommissioning: 4000,
      totalMileage: 1000,
      otherWages: 2000,
      totalDaysPaid: 220,
    }
    const wrapper = shallow(<AwerageDailyComponent values={values} />)
    expect(wrapper.find('label').text()).toEqual(
      '13. Average Daily Wage (([7]$45,000.00 + [9]$4,000.00 + [11]$1,000.00 + [12]$2,000.00) / [8]220):'
    )-
  })
```